# How do browsers de-duplicate HTTP requests

Tags: html, http, browser, fetch

When a HTML page has an image embedded twice:

```
<img src="foo.jpg">
<img src="foo.jpg">
```

This results in only 1 HTTP request, even if there were no caching headers. This makes a lot of sense.

I'm curious under which circumstances a browser will do this. Will it do it for 2 subsequent `fetch()` calls? For all 'safe' http methods? If yes, how much time does there need to be between calls before it will do a new one? Or maybe it will only de-duplicate if the last one is still in flight? What heuristics will browsers use to figure out if requests can be de-duplicated?

Comment: The stated criteria for up/down vote is, in part, "shows research effort". The scenarios you ask about all seem pretty easy to test. What were your results?

Comment: I did a little bit of testing myself. Based on the results, I'm guessing that this happens when you make a request for a url that is still being resolved in a previous request.

Comment: I think we have different scenarios here. In a static HTML document, it makes sense to reuse resources that are linked several times; failing to do so would feel like a bug. When you issue a fetch call from JavaScript you have code that explicitly asks the browser to download a resource. And there're probably two decades between both features. A better comparison would be "img tag in _different_ documents" vs "different fetch" calls.

Comment: @Ouroborus I'm less interested in deducing this through testing behavior and more interested in an answer that has a source.

Comment: "_I'm less interested in deducing this through testing behavior and more interested in an answer that has a source_": This is a great example of juxtaposing [computer] [science](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Science) and [history](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History): one is concerned with something that is considered valid because it can be reproduced and observed in the current state of reality. The other is concerned with something that was claimed to have happened in the past.

Comment: @jsejcksn in this case the question was more about getting comprehensive information, because there's a LOT of factors that could influence whether a request gets de-duplicated, such as (certain, but not all) headers, which method was used, whether that method is safe/idempotent and I'd imagine in circumstances the state of the cache /w things like the Vary header. The matrix is too large for some rudimentary testing.

Comment: @Ouroborus Plus I'd magine there's a number of hidden variables here. Worth noting that I don't have a single specific use-case or problem, I'm building something similar and accuracy is kind of important.

Comment: Lastly, it's generally not recommended to implement web standards based on other's implementations, because this can carry forward bugs they may have. Generally not against 'just try it out', but this is just not one of the cases where that's a useful answer.